Fit a 3D parabola using sliced 2D gaussian distributions
I have a 3D spray distribution that should fit to a 3D parabolic function. Captured data using a beam to slice the 3D parabola at different heights will fit 2D gaussians. How would I fit or estimate the 3D parabolic distribution using the 2D gaussian distributions taken from different slices of the the 3D parabola?

Can you clarify what the input data looks like? Can you clarify what kind of fit you're looking for? e.g. a maximum likelihood estimate fit, or an ordinary least squares fit?

@NickODell The data of each slice will originally be (x,y) point data corresponding to "events" in the image plane. I think the best method will be to "bin" this data to create an (x,y,i) data points corresponding to (x point, y point, intensity of events). This is where I'm unsure how to proceed. I am going to have this data at a few different heights. I could create (x,y,z,i) points and try to fit to the data (would have to be LSQ because not i.i.d?) or calculate the gaussians at each z height and do some fitting of the 2D gaussian parameters to 3D gaussian parameters. Does this help?

Could you post a representative dataset.

@jlandercy I’m still working on machine vision algorithm to capture the data, should be a week or so and I’ll post

I ended up deciding that an exponential function was a better representation of the 3D spray profile then a parabola. This is since the effects on the spray droplets such as drag and velocity follow a exponential distribution naturally.
It turns out that the principal axis of equal probability ellipsoids are proportional to the eigenvalues of the 2D Gaussian's covariance matrix. So fitting an exponential to the eigenvalues of 2D sliced Gaussians at different heights and doing the same fit for center points of the Gaussian and twist angle, one can fully characterize a 3D profile.
Then you can get out a 2D Gaussian at any height using the below function:
def _get_2d_gaussian_at_height(self, height:float,x_coords, y_coords) -> np.ndarray:
        a_x, b_x, c_x = self.x_center_curve_coefficients
        a_y, b_y, c_y = self.y_center_curve_coefficients
        x_center = self._exp_func(height, a_x, b_x, c_x)
        y_center = self._exp_func(height, a_y, b_y, c_y)

        #the square roots of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix will be the standard deviations along the principal components
        x_eigenvalue, y_eigenvalue = self._get_eigenvalues_at_height(height)
        if x_eigenvalue < 0 or y_eigenvalue < 0:
            raise ValueError(f"Eigenvalues at height {height} are less than 0, setting to 0")
        sigma_x = np.sqrt(x_eigenvalue)
        sigma_y = np.sqrt(y_eigenvalue)
        theta = self._get_theta_at_height(height)
        return self._gaussian_2d_generator(x_coords, y_coords, x_center, y_center, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta)


There is a fairly straightforward way to do it with scipy.
First we create some trial dataset (3D Gaussian):
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

mu = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
sigma = np.array([
    [3., 0.5, -0.3],
    [0.5, 2., 0.8],
    [-0.3, 0.8, 1.]
])

law = stats.multivariate_normal(mean=mu, cov=sigma)
data = law.rvs(30_000)

Now we can regress/fit the point cloud using the fit method of the multivariate_normal object:
stats.multivariate_normal.fit(data)
#(array([0.99285832, 1.99391781, 3.00402304]),
# array([[ 2.97516577,  0.4876874 , -0.30404617],
#        [ 0.4876874 ,  1.96983946,  0.79608385],
#        [-0.30404617,  0.79608385,  0.98948756]]))


Looks promising but will this work without randomly distributed z points? I will have a ton of x,y data at only a few z heights. I see in your example there are 30,000 randomly distributed points. The thing is in my data the z points are not randomly distributed.

Could you provide a sample dataset that is representative.
